# The link to meta in "this is a comment" LQP auto-comment doesn't fit if the comment is to another answer

Tags: bug, review-queues

**For example, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/12088189)**.
<sub>[*screenshot's here in case that it gets deleted.*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LKVVd.png)</sub>

Well, it should be a comment (an edit also works though), but it's to another answer, rather than the question.

In this case, let me quote our auto-comment:

> This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).

The last link, "[provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead)", doesn't fit the answer example because which isn't a comment to the asker, but an answerer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do not like the auto comment you can always use your own comment and then chose no comment from the auto comment selection.

If you do not want to have to type the same comment over and over you can also use the [AutoReviewComments](https://stackapps.com/questions/2116/autoreviewcomments-pro-forma-comments-for-se) user script and add the comment to that. Then if the auto comment isn't worded correctly for the situation you can fall back to your own custom comments.